# Cannot read properties of undefined. Latest Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Why am I getting an error and how can I fix it? Using latest Angular.

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')**

JSON:

```
{
"settings": [
    {
        "test": "test",
        "title": "Service 1"
    }
],
"services": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Service 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Service 2"
    }
]
```

}

app.component.html

```
<p>service id {{ service.id }}</p>
```

app.component.ts

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Get data
    this.api.getApi()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.data = res;
        // Get service
        this.service = this.data.services.filter((obj: any) => {
          return obj.id === this.id;
        });
      });
  }
```

Comment: Please do a search of this site (or via Google) for `[Angular] Cannot read properties of undefined`. There are literally thousands of existing posts here that have been answered - surely at least one of them would give you a means of solving this issue without creating yet another duplicate post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `.filter` function returns an array and not object, If you are receiving the data properly inside the `service` array, you need to loop in that array in order to get the `id` field something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let s of service">
  {{ s.id }}
</div>
```

But first try `console.log` the service variable to see if you got the proper data